# Android Volley not sending POST or GET Params

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send data to server using Volley and I couldn't able to retrive the data from server, below is my volley code -

```
final RequestQueue Q = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    //Handler h = new Handler();
    final JsonObjectRequest get_j = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
            //set_t();
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Q.stop();
                //t.setText(response.getString("ip"));
                if(response.getString("STATUS").equals("PASS")){
                    t.setText(response.getString("ID"));
                }
                else{
                    t.setText("Oops..! Some thing went wrong");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                t.setText("Error...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Q.stop();
            t.setText(error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("ADDRESS_TYPE","3");
            params.put("DOOR_NO","XYZ/123");
            return params;
        }
    };
    Q.add(get_j);
```

And below is the code of PHP Server -

```
<?php $data["STATUS"] = "PASS"; $data["ID"] = "xx".$_GET['DOOR_NO']; echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

Comment: are you creating a get request with params?

Comment: both the ways its not working,

Comment: is onResponse getting called ?

Comment: post the errors log...use POST in volley and your script not GET

Comment: your first param you didn't initialized in php file??

Comment: Yes, On response getting called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask